# Play! framework morphia module group aggregation by date bucket

Tags: javascript, mongodb, playframework, mapreduce, morphia

I'm using the Play! framework morphia-mongodb module, and I see it has nice built-ins for doing group aggregation.  Unfortunately all the examples only show grouping/aggregating by a fixed field, whereas I need to aggregate by a calculated field: timestamp grouped by day.  I'm wondering if anyone knows the right approach to this?

I know I can just resort to a native map/reduce (which itself took a little digging to figure out, so I'm posting here for reference, using Movies and showtimes):

```
        DBCollection coll = Movie.col();
        String map = "function() { " +
            (this.showtime.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + this.showtime.getDate()}; "
            + "var key = {date: this.showtime.getFullYear() + '/' 
            + (this.showtime.getMonth() + 1)       
            + '/' + this.showtime.getDate()}; "
            + "emit(key, {count: 1}); }";

        String reduce = "function(key, values) { var sum = 0; "
            + " values.forEach( function(value) {sum += value['count'];} );"
            + " return {count: sum}; }";

        String output = "dailyShowingCount";

        MapReduceOutput out = coll.mapReduce(
            map, reduce, output, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.REPLACE, null);

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");    
        for (Iterator<DBObject> itr = out.results().iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            DBObject dbo = itr.next();

            String compoundKeyStr = dbo.get("_id").toString();
            String compoundValStr = dbo.get("value").toString();

            DBObject compKey = (DBObject)JSON.parse(compoundKeyStr);
            DBObject compVal = (DBObject)JSON.parse(compoundValStr);

            //don't know why count returns as a float, but it does, so i need to convert    
            Long dCount = new Double(
               Double.parseDouble(compVal.get("count").toString())
            ).longValue();

            Date date = df.parse(compKey.get("date").toString());
        }
```

But if there's already an elegant built-in way to do this aggregation with the morphia module, I'd like to use that instead.  One thought I had was to create a virtual field in my java class (e.g. "getDay()") and then group/aggregate by that.  Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a derived column in your model and save it into the database.

```
@Entity Movie extends Model {
   public Date showTime;
   private Date showTimeDate;
   @OnUpdate
   @OnAdd
   void calcShowTimeDate() {
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      c.setTime(showTime);
      c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
      c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
      c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
      c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
      showTimeDate = c.getTime()
   }
}
```

Then you could aggregate on `showTimeDate` column following the instruction at http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.4d/statistics